# Electrical advice concerning a 220v dryer outlet and circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

I have a 220v line that feeds my electric stove, the line is accessible via a junction box in the basement. The line is fed from the service panel and is protected via 4 30 amp "cartridge" fuses.

My question is this:  Can I run a line from the existing junction box to a new 220v outlet for my electric dryer? (new outlet would be less than 15ft from junction)
I know that technically the line can handle the load, and it "can" be done, I want to know is

1. Is it legal in the state of Massachusetts to do such?
2. will the (4)  30 amp cartridge fuses be adequate for the load?
   Original Cloth type wiring from service panel to the junction box exists, I would, of course, install appropriate wire for the dryer outlet.

All wires have been inspected by a licensed electrician and are in great condition.
All I want to do is add a second 220v outlet to the circuit already in place for the stove.

[image: Junction]
[image: My 2 service panels]

Comment: Can you provide us with a photo of the inside of the existing junction box? I'm wondering what wiring method this precisely is...

Comment: Do you have 120V from the range receptacle to its housing?

Comment: I have 110 on both legs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more problems than just connecting up a dryer. Buy the way in answer to your question. **NO** you can't tap a range feeder and supply a dryer with it.

First you say your range feeder is protected by cartridge fuses. That would mean that you have and old Edison Base Fuse Panel or worse. In this state the AHJ recommend that when we as electrical contractors go into a dwelling it is our job to recommend the owner replace them.

Second NEC Article 220.55 requires a separate circuit for household ranges. The size is determined by the nameplate rating of the range. Since we don't know what size range the homeowner is going to install, we usually run a 50A circuit which covers all ranges up to 12KW. The minimum circuit it requires is a #8 wire and an over current protection of 40A. So you need to replace the 30A circuit you currently have.

Third NEC Article 220.54 requires a separate circuit to be run for the dryer. and It needs to be able to handle 5KW or the nameplate rating whichever is larger. So a minimum circuit would be a 30A circuit.

So if you have the capability in you panel to install a 50A circuit for your range. I suppose you could run a new range circuit and use the old range circuit for the dryer and relabel your panel to reflect the change.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: Can you explain how 220.54/220.55 implement a dedicated branch circuit requirement for the appliances in question? I don't see how you got from the text of those sections to your conclusion...

Comment: The comments actually come out of the 2014 NEC "Handbook" almost verbatim.

Comment: I have added pictures. the old service panel feeds the stove via cartridge fuses. The newer breaker panel feeds the rest of the house.  I have no space available for a new circuit.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate for me.  I will have to come up with a new plan. I will end up going with gas, I believe it will be cheaper to run 30ft of pipe and connect then to replace/upgrade the service panel.

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician -- huh.  that's...interesting.  it's something I certainly would not have read into the text of those sections o.o

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Go figure, but that's why I always try and purchase the Handbook. It seems to make life simpler.